Geometry nodes - Avoid "All Curves" in Sample Curve node

I'm making an array with constant step geometry nodes group setup. I'm using Sample Curve Node. I need similar result, which prodused by "all curves button" for this situation. But I also have to avoid "all curves" button. Since you can adjust Curve Index field in Sample Curve Node (which do the job well, but only on a single spline) I can not understand: why I can't just use Index Node on Curve Index filed to distribute by points on all curves...


https://i.imgur.com/ji1yAoU.gif
